# Memory leak occurs only on ios 10.x devices, but fine on ios 9.3

Tags: xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, nsdata, mupdf

I've created [an example project](https://github.com/lexboss93/iosleaktest) that reproduces the issue (clone-and-run ready).
What project does it takes an input pdf file and creates a thumbnail for each page. In real project the worker thread iterates through many pdf files with many pages (~100 pages).

What curious for me is that on ios 9.3 (13E233, iPad Air simulator) there is no memory leak. After test method completion Activity monitor shows memory used 48.4mb. But ios 10.x (14C89, 14A345) simulators took memory up to 782.7 mb! Memory leak occurs on real device as well - ipad air with ios 10.2.1 (14D27).

Each pdf page is processed through this method:

```
CGSize SaveThumbnailGetSize (PDFDocument pdfDocument, int pdfPage, string filename)
    {
        CGSize size = pdfDocument.GetPageSize (pdfPage);
        nfloat K = 750f / size.Width < 1 ? 750f / size.Width : 1;

        MuPDFLib.Cookie cookie = new MuPDFLib.Cookie ();

        using (NativeBitmap img = pdfDocument.RenderToBitmap (PDFDocument.context, new CGRect (0, 0, (int)Math.Round (size.Width * K), (int)Math.Round (size.Height * K)), K, pdfPage, 0, ref cookie)) {
            NSError err = null;
            using (var uimg = ((UIImage)img)) {

                // Memory leak occurs only with this line. If comment this, memory leak will no occur.
                using (NSData data = uimg.AsJPEG (0.4f)) { 

                    //[optional line]
                    //data.Save (filename, true, out err);
                }
            }

            if (err != null) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Could not save thumbnail: {0}", err);
            }
        }

        return size;
    }
```

I think something wrong happens in this line:

```
NSData data = uimg.AsJPEG (0.4f)
```

Also I've tried to surround methods/usings/code-blocks with NSAutoreleasePool but with no success (but I guess xamarin should do it automatically).

Some system info:

- Xamarin Studio Community Version 6.2 (build 1829)
- Apple Developer Tools Xcode 8.2.1 (11766.1) Build 8C1002
- Xamarin.iOS
  Version: 10.4.0.128 (Xamarin Studio Community)
  Hash: ba11e48
  Branch: cycle9
  Build date: 2017-03-10 08:48:04-0500
- Operating System
  Mac OS X 10.12.3

**UPD (04.04.2017):**
Created a bug report:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54443

Also after upgradging xamarin, xcode and os got new available iOS system - 10.3 (14E269) - and it isn't affected by memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Monitor is unfortunately not helpful for measuring memory leaks.

The only way to check for memory leaks is using the 'Leaks' tool within Instruments. This would also tell you exactly which object(s) is being leaked

My first suspicion is that you are just seeing some kind of cache, which iOS would free if memory got low - if that is the case, there is no leak.